# jquery.exif.js with localhost - badrequest issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, exif, bad-request

Good day!

I am attempting to run this plugin - http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/exifjquery/jquery.exif.js

On an asp.net website. Currently I am running the site through my local IIS or via my asp.net development server.

Whenever this plugin attempts to call `function sendRequest(strURL, fncCallback, fncError, aRange, bAcceptRanges, iFileSize){//...}` line 195 `oHTTP.send(null);`

The images I have loaded come back with a badrequest(400).

The request url is something like: *192.168.#.###/MyWebsite/img1.jpg* or *localhost/MyWebsite/img1.jpg*.

I tried copy/pasting this example as is(I changed refs to point to my directories) into a new project with no success: [JQuery EXIF Demo](http://blog.rrikesh.com/demo/jquery-exif.html)

Needless to say, I get empty results when calling exif methods.

I don't know if this will help but - [Request Headers](http://sdrv.ms/13opryl)

The plugin does not work for me as it stands. I think it is some kind of domain request issue.

Any help with this would be immensely appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the line you give us here `localhost/MyWebsite/img1.jpg` I understand that you run your site with the web server of the visual studio, that is use a different port than the default 80.

So what I expect to see there was something like `localhost:8080/MyWebsite/img1.jpg`, with the port, so, with out the port is probably call something else that ether not exist, ether not the same web as you work - and that's the reason of your error.

Comment: I believe you are correct! I added a specific port number to the url of the image and it is now working. Thanks very much!